# Loading np.array from csv dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a dataframe with columns values that are np.arrays. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"id":1, "sample": np.array([1,2,3])}, {"id":2, "sample": np.array([2,3,4])}])
df.to_csv("./tmp.csv", index=False)
```

if I save df to csv and load it again I get "sample" column as strings.

```
df_from_csv = pd.read_csv("./tmp.csv")   
df_from_csv == pd.DataFrame([{"id":1, "sample": '[1 2 3]')}, {"id":2, "sample": '[2 3 4]')}])
True
```

Is there a better way to save/load my data that does no requiere manually passing '[1 2 3]' to ist corresponding array?

Comment: This is not a reliable way of saving such a dataframe.  As you found it writes the `str` display of each array element.  `csv` is inherently a 2d format, so can't handle the implied third dimension of these arrays.  If the arrays are large enough, that `str` will be condensed, with '...'.  Such an array cannot be recovered.

Comment: @hpaulj any suggestion on how to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a converter in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval
import re

def to_array(x):
    return np.array(literal_eval(re.sub('\s+', ',', x)))

df_from_csv = pd.read_csv("./tmp.csv", converters={'sample': to_array}) 

#    id     sample
# 0   1  [1, 2, 3]
# 1   2  [2, 3, 4]

df_from_csv.loc[0, 'sample']

# array([1, 2, 3])
```